Chinese martial arts movie with moving statues
I remember seeing this Chinese martial arts movie in the 90s. I'm not sure when it was made so it could be older.
From what I can remember, the protagonist is training in a Shaolin place. He has long black hair.
The thing that was memorable for me was that he took this martial arts test. There are these gold or silver statues that move and attack him, and he has to hit marks on them for them to stop moving. Once, he does so, he moves on to another room with another group of gold/silver statues in them, and so on.

A  Shaolin monk with long hair? c'mon...

Does American Shaolin rings a bell? (the statues are wooden, though).

It might be Return of the 18 Bronzemen aka The 18 Bronzemen Part 2
Here's a trailer:




Please improve your answer by explaining how you think this matches the film described in the question.

Yes! This is it!! Thanks so much!

Since you didn't elaborate on the types of statues involved, it could be the movie "Raiders Of Wu Tang" which is an old martial arts flick in which the hero has to take a test where he has to fight 24 bronze horses with different martial arts techniques.  See the following for more info
http://www.badmovies.org/movies/raiderswutang/

It's not this one. The statues were humanoid (and bald). They weren't horses.

I think this may be an old Jacky Chan movie.. seems to have two names, "shaolin wooden men" and Shaolin chamber of death 
I could have sworn there was a movie titled something like "108 wooden dummies" so if this isn't it you may want to follow that lead.
